# i added Hibernate option in Ubuntu 12.04 but not working

Tags: 12.04, hibernate, system-monitor

i created hibernate option using _

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

and i added this in that file_

```
[Re-enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

but its not working. when i click on it, come to desktop page after some tym
what need to do . is anything wrong?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x426556e7

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    81915434    40957686   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        81915496   625137344   271610924+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        81915498   255995774    87040138+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       255995838   430076114    87040138+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       430076178   625137344    97530583+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2025828    1372148     653680          0     135104     772580
-/+ buffers/cache:     464464    1561364
Swap:      4194300          0    4194300

#free
 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
 Mem:       2025828     864896    1160932          0      28972     380768
 -/+ buffers/cache:     455156    1570672
 Swap:      4194300      79680    4114620
```

Comment: You might not have room for hibernation. Please give the results of the following: "sudo fdisk -l && free"

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x426556e7
 Device Boot Start  End Blocks Id  System
/dev/sda1   *   63    81915434    40957686   83  Linux
/dev/sda2 81915496   625137344   271610924+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5 81915498   255995774    87040138+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6 255995838   430076114    87040138+  82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: Thanks, you've got a big enough swap file - maybe 50 times too big.  You missed the free command though, which would tell us if it was using it.  Please type the command "free" and give us the output.

Comment: I confirm the correct file is /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla, not /var/lib...

Comment: Something strange here - the swap partition appears to be huge - /dev/sda6 is 166Gb. Maybe someone could check my figures?  The swap given above is 4Gb.  Is it a swap file?  Linux hibernation to a swap file is none-trivial and needs to be set up correctly by my understanding.

Comment: then what goes wrong, i gave 4GB is wright. and is using it, bt when i click on hibernate option it shows _PM:swap header not found_ ,
   is it require separate partition?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit files in: `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`.

You could do the following:

- Open the file.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

- Type the following and save:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

- Log out and log back in.

Comment: it is showing _


    option_instat_callback:error -84
    PM:swap header not found

Comment: when? where? how?

Comment: when i click on hibernate option, after that showing black screen and after some time .. gave that out put , and come back to desktop.

Comment: Make sure `pm-hibernate` is installed. Open a terminal and run `pm-hibernate`. See if it hibernates your machine.

Comment: this is giving me black screen and showing errors_

option_instat_callback:error -84 PM:swap header not found

Comment: Are you using a swap file? Did you make one after the installation? Check this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43508/debian-hibernate-problem-pm-swap-header-not-found

Comment: yes, i didnt created swap space at installation, i created ne file.

Comment: have a look at this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap#Swap_file_resuming

Comment: is i need to create separate partition instead swap-file?

Comment: most probably, yes.

Comment: ok, i ll try it , tnx

Answer (score 0):

Might be a silly reason, but I had to update my graphics driver with the additional drivers program for mine to work.

Comment: then what i need to do?

Comment: It was just a matter of going into the additional drivers program in the list for me. My card is an ati. One drive works, one would not install.